# spring aspect to detect custom transaction annotation

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-transactions

We have a custom annotation wrapping the spring `@Transactional`.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(value="my_txn_mgr",readOnly=false)
public @interface MyWriteTxn {}
```

When I try to write an aspect which will intercept this annotation, it does not work.

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="@annotation(transactional)", throwing="exception")
public void processError(JoinPoint jp,Transactional transactional,Exception exception)
```

If i directly give `@Transactional` it works.

Since the annotation is derived , looks like the pointcut has to be defined appropriately. Has anybody faced the above issue and found soltuion ?

Thanks

Comment: So why don't you use your aspect in the pointcut?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, please clarify. Do you want an aspect which uses `@Transactional` which also includes your custom annotation?

Comment: My aspect is a generic aspect which needs to be triggered on all methods which have @Transactional annotation.The issue is there are different custom annotations that are being used in the application. Since all these annotations are wrapping spring Transactional annotation , I should be able to trap it in a generic way ( In fact I believe thats how spring also detects the custom transaction annotations that are created )

Comment: Yes Deinum - thanks for making the problem clear.

Comment: Since Java does not have annoation inheritance I don't think it is possible to create such an pointcut. Spring will simply inspect all annotations including annotations on the annotation declartion itself to provide this functionality.

Comment: Ok. Probably need to dig further in Spring code to find out how. Thanks for the information.